# Almacenamiento "modo privado" de Fotos

Tags: android, android-studio, seguridad, android-intent

Bueno deseo tomar una Foto y guardarlo sin que la foto se muestre desde la galeria.
este es el codigo que uso:

```
File MiFotoTemporal = new File(RUTAFOTO+ NOMBREFOTO);
MiFotoTemporal.createNewFile();
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(MiFotoTemporal);
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);  
cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);          
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, requestCode_tomarFoto);
```

Comment: Ya tienes la foto guardada en la carpeta?

Comment: No ,con eso mando un  intent a la camara para tomar una foto  y se guarda normal en la RUTAFOTO. no obstante el dilema es que deseo no se vea la imagen desde la galeria

Comment: agrego respuesta :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplemente debes incluir un archivo vacío llamado **.nomedia** en la carpeta donde guardas las fotos. Realizando algo así:

```
        //ruta de la carpeta donde guardes las fotos
        String rutacarpeta = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/carpetanueva/";
        //file ruta + .nomedia
        File file = new File(rutacarpeta + ".nomedia");
        //comprueba si existe o no el archivo
        if (!file.exists()) {
            //si no existe, lo crea
            try {
                file.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Teniendo ese archivo en tu carpeta ninguna galería debería mostrar las fotos.

Imagino que lo sabes ya que estás guardando las fotos pero por si acaso, recuerda que desde [**Android 5.0**, necesitas pedir los permisos, en este caso de almacenamiento](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Comment: Esto lo desconocía, no lo he intentado pero al parecer funciona: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xovAHo0zGBQ

Comment: Así es como yo siempre lo he realizado y hasta hoy sin problemas! @Jorgesys

Comment: veo que incluso puedo agregar el archivo manualmente y se escondé mi folder, excelente!!! :D

Answer (score 0):

Me funciono Perfecto usar el archivo ".nomedia" dentro de la carpeta
Adicionalmente en mi caso no se refleja el cambio en mis apks de Galerias

Para ver el cambio reflejado en las aplicaciones de Galeria, hice lo siguiente
Borrar Datos y Forzar Detencion de la Aplicacion 
Configuracion > Aplicaciones > Galeria > Almacenamiento y Borrar Datos